Agricultural Tiling using ArcGIS Pro
I have an ArcGIS Pro Basic Subscription.
I work at a farm and we deal with agricultural tiling. Some places that do tiling for us send it in points rather than lines, which make it very hard to use. It is not ordered in a way that I am able to easily use the ArcGIS points to line function. Attached should be an example of the tile as a line (what we want) and one with points (what we don't want). The first picture is an example of what we receive, and the second one being what we want as the end result, although they are different places in this example.


How can I convert the points into lines?

You may need to rasterize your points then vectorize your raster as lines.

What would be the easiest way to do that, or a good pointer to a help guide to do so? (I have no experience doing either of those two things)

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/rasterize-features-function.htm

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polyline.htm
